# ssh port forward issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I would port forward with ssh but when I try to do that the ssh client always log in instead of port forward

```
ssh -i /mnt/storage/jenkins/.ssh/prod_key jenkins@targetmachine.com -L 1868:database.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

I can't understand why. I tried to change the sequence but it doesn-t works.

I changed in the /etc/ssh/sshd conf

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per `man ssh`

> -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.

Comment: thats right. I just want to forward ports

Comment: Solved with the "&" at the end of command